# How to store a unique query RESULT into DBeaver variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, dbeaver

i'm trying to store some data in Dbeaver binding variables like these:

```
--test
@set test = good
--testQ
@set testQ = select date from table where id = 1;
```

I need to store the query result, NOT the query statment, someone knows if this is posible?

Comment: I have tried many things and have had no success. Also very interested in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@set testQ = (select date from table where id = 1)

select * from anotherTable where date = :testQ;
```

It is important not use ; in variable declaration, because will duplicate the command finalization